# Writing expression in terms of $\ln2$ and $\ln3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Express $\ln \sqrt[3]{32}$ in terms of $\ln2$ and/or $\ln3$

My try:

$\ln\sqrt[3]{32}= \ln(32^{1/3})= \frac{1}{3} \ln32 = \frac{1}{3} \ln2^5$

This isn't correct because there's a $5$...how do you solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** How did you go from $\ln(32^{1/3})$ to $\frac{1}{3}\ln(32)$? Can you make the same step at the end?

Comment: $\frac{5}{3}\textrm{ln}2$? Is that correct?

Comment: @user4150: yes, indeed it is correct!

Answer (score 2):

$\ln(32^{1/3}) = 1/3(\ln 2^5 ) = \frac{5}{3} \ln 2$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$$
\color{#0000ff}{\large\ln\pars{\root[{3 \atop}]{\vphantom{\large A}32}}}
=
\ln\pars{2^{5/3}}
=
{5 \over 3}\,\ln\left(2\right)
=\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\braces{{\ln\pars{2} \over \ln\pars{2}} + {\expo{\ln\pars{2}} \over \expo{\ln\pars{3}}}}\,\ln\left(2\right)}
$$